# Boost Spirit template specialization failure

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Below is a very compact version of a grammar I'm trying to write using *boost::spirit::qi*.
Environment: VS2013, x86, Boost1.64
When #including the header file, the compiler complains about the line

```
rBlock = "{" >> +(rInvocation) >> "}";
```

with a very long log (I've only copied the beginning and the end):

> more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list
>   ...
>   ...
>    see reference to function template instantiation
>   'boost::spirit::qi::rule
>   &boost::spirit::qi::rule::operator =>(const Expr &)' being compiled

Where is my mistake?

The header file:

```
//mygrammar.h
#pragma once 
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace myNS
{

    typedef std::string Identifier;
    typedef ::boost::spirit::qi::rule <const char*, Identifier()> myIdentifierRule;

    typedef ::boost::variant<char, int> Expression;
    typedef ::boost::spirit::qi::rule <const char*, Expression()> myExpressionRule;

    struct IdntifierEqArgument
    {
        Identifier ident;
        Expression arg;
    };

    typedef ::boost::variant < IdntifierEqArgument, Expression >  Argument;
    typedef ::boost::spirit::qi::rule <const char*, Argument()> myArgumentRule;

    typedef ::std::vector<Argument> ArgumentList;
    typedef ::boost::spirit::qi::rule <const char*, myNS::ArgumentList()> myArgumentListRule;


    struct Invocation
    {
        Identifier identifier;
        ::boost::optional<ArgumentList> args;
    };
    typedef ::boost::spirit::qi::rule <const char*, Invocation()> myInvocationRule;


    typedef ::std::vector<Invocation> Block;
    typedef ::boost::spirit::qi::rule <const char*, myNS::Block()> myBlockRule;

}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    myNS::IdntifierEqArgument,
    (auto, ident)
    (auto, arg)
    );
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    myNS::Invocation,
    (auto, identifier)
    (auto, args)
    );

namespace myNS
{
    struct myRules
    {
        myIdentifierRule rIdentifier;
        myExpressionRule rExpression;
        myArgumentRule rArgument;
        myArgumentListRule rArgumentList;
        myInvocationRule rInvocation;
        myBlockRule rBlock;

        myRules()
        {
            using namespace ::boost::spirit;
            using namespace ::boost::spirit::qi;

            rIdentifier = as_string[((qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_'))]; 
            rExpression = char_ | int_;
            rArgument = (rIdentifier >> "=" >> rExpression) | rExpression;
            rArgumentList = rArgument >> *("," >> rArgument);
            rInvocation = rIdentifier >> "(" >> -rArgumentList >> ")";
            rBlock = "{" >> +(rInvocation) >> "}";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I'd consider raising the abstraction a bit by renaming `IdentifierEqnArgument` to something more expressive, like `NamedArgument`. By the former convention you could have named Expression `AnyLooseCharacterOrIntegralNumber` instead. It is probably clear which is better, and why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where the issue is triggered, but it clearly is a symptom of too many ambiguities in the attribute forwarding rules.

> *Conceptually this could be triggered by your attribute types having similar/compatible layouts. In language theory, you're looking at a mismatch between C++'s nominative type system versus the approximation of structural typing in the attribute propagation system. But enough theorism :)*

I don't think `attr_cast<>` will save you here as it probably uses the same mechanics and heuristics under the hood.

It drew my attention that making the `ArgumentList` optional is ... not very useful (as an empty list already accurately reflects absense of arguments).

So I tried simplifying the rules:

```
rArgumentList = -(rArgument % ',');
rInvocation   = rIdentifier >> '(' >> rArgumentList >> ')';
```

And the declared attribute type can be simply `ArgumentList` instead of `boost::optional::ArgumentList`.

This turns out to remove the ambiguity when propagating into the `vector<Invocation>`, so ... you're saved.

> If this feels "accidental" to you, you should! What would I do if this hadn't removed the ambiguity "by chance"? I'd have created a semantic action to propagate the Invocation by simpler mechanics. There's a good chance that `fusion::push_back(_val, _1)` or similar would have worked.
>
> See also [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

### Review And Demo

In the cleaned up review here I present a few fixes/improvements and a test run that dumps the parsed AST.

1. Separate AST from parser (you don't want use `qi` in the AST types. You specifically do not want `using namespace` directives in the face of generic template libraries)
2. Do not use `auto` in the adapt macros. That's not a feature. Instead, since you can ostensibly use C++11, use the C++11 (decltype) based macros

   ```
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myAST::IdntifierEqArgument, ident,arg);
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myAST::Invocation, identifier,args);
   ```
3. AST is leading (also, prefer c++11 for clarity):

   ```
   namespace myAST {
       using Identifier = std::string;
       using Expression = boost::variant<char, int>;

       struct IdntifierEqArgument {
           Identifier ident;
           Expression arg;
       };

       using Argument = boost::variant<IdntifierEqArgument, Expression>;

       using ArgumentList = std::vector<Argument>;

       struct Invocation {
           Identifier identifier;
           ArgumentList args;
       };

       using Block = std::vector<Invocation>;
   }
   ```

   It's nice to have the definitions separate
4. Regarding the parser,

   - I'd prefer the `qi::grammar` convention. Also,
   - You didn't declare any of the rules with a skipper. I "guessed" from context that whitespace is insignificant outside of the rules for `Expression` and `Identifier`.
   - Expression ate every `char_`, so also would eat `')'` or even `'3'`. I noticed this only when testing and after debugging with:

     ```
     //#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
     BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(rBlock)(rInvocation)(rIdentifier)(rArgumentList)(rArgument)(rExpression))
     ```

     I highly recommend using these facilities
5. All in all the parser comes down to

   ```
   namespace myNS {
       namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

       template <typename Iterator = char const*>
       struct myRules : qi::grammar<Iterator, myAST::Block()> {

           myRules() : myRules::base_type(start) {
               rIdentifier   = qi::raw [(qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')];
               rExpression   = qi::alpha | qi::int_;
               rArgument     = (rIdentifier >> '=' >> rExpression) | rExpression;
               rArgumentList = -(rArgument % ',');
               rInvocation   = rIdentifier >> '(' >> rArgumentList >> ')';
               rBlock        = '{' >> +rInvocation >> '}';
               start         = qi::skip(qi::space) [ rBlock ];

               BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(rBlock)(rInvocation)(rIdentifier)(rArgumentList)(rArgument)(rExpression))
           }

         private:
           qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Block()> start;
           using Skipper = qi::space_type;

           qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Argument(), Skipper>     rArgument;
           qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::ArgumentList(), Skipper> rArgumentList;
           qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Invocation(), Skipper>   rInvocation;
           qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Block(), Skipper>        rBlock;
           // implicit lexemes
           qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Identifier()>   rIdentifier;
           qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Expression()>   rExpression;
       };
   }
   ```
6. Adding a test driver

   ```
   int main() {
       std::string const input = R"(
   {
       foo()
       bar(a, b, 42)
       qux(someThing_awful01 = 9)
   }
   )";
       auto f = input.data(), l = f + input.size();

       myAST::Block block;
       bool ok = parse(f, l, myNS::myRules<>{}, block);

       if (ok) {
           std::cout << "Parse success\n";

           for (auto& invocation : block) {
               std::cout << invocation.identifier << "(";
               for (auto& arg : invocation.args) std::cout << arg << ",";
               std::cout << ")\n";
           }
       }
       else
           std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

       if (f!=l)
           std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
   }
   ```

### Complete Demo

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8378169c4e29dae6)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace myAST {
    using Identifier = std::string;
    using Expression = boost::variant<char, int>;

    struct IdntifierEqArgument {
        Identifier ident;
        Expression arg;
    };

    using Argument = boost::variant<IdntifierEqArgument, Expression>;

    using ArgumentList = std::vector<Argument>;

    struct Invocation {
        Identifier identifier;
        ArgumentList args;
    };

    using Block = std::vector<Invocation>;

    // for debug printing
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, myAST::IdntifierEqArgument const& named) {
        return os << named.ident << "=" << named.arg;
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myAST::IdntifierEqArgument, ident,arg);
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myAST::Invocation, identifier,args);

namespace myNS {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename Iterator = char const*>
    struct myRules : qi::grammar<Iterator, myAST::Block()> {

        myRules() : myRules::base_type(start) {
            rIdentifier   = qi::raw [(qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')];
            rExpression   = qi::alpha | qi::int_;
            rArgument     = (rIdentifier >> '=' >> rExpression) | rExpression;
            rArgumentList = -(rArgument % ',');
            rInvocation   = rIdentifier >> '(' >> rArgumentList >> ')';
            rBlock        = '{' >> +rInvocation >> '}';
            start         = qi::skip(qi::space) [ rBlock ];

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(rBlock)(rInvocation)(rIdentifier)(rArgumentList)(rArgument)(rExpression))
        }

      private:
        qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Block()> start;
        using Skipper = qi::space_type;

        qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Argument(), Skipper>     rArgument;
        qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::ArgumentList(), Skipper> rArgumentList;
        qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Invocation(), Skipper>   rInvocation;
        qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Block(), Skipper>        rBlock;
        // implicit lexemes
        qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Identifier()>   rIdentifier;
        qi::rule<Iterator, myAST::Expression()>   rExpression;
    };
}

int main() {
    std::string const input = R"(
{
    foo()
    bar(a, b, 42)
    qux(someThing_awful01 = 9)
}
)";
    auto f = input.data(), l = f + input.size();

    myAST::Block block;
    bool ok = parse(f, l, myNS::myRules<>{}, block);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";

        for (auto& invocation : block) {
            std::cout << invocation.identifier << "(";
            for (auto& arg : invocation.args) std::cout << arg << ",";
            std::cout << ")\n";
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints output

```
Parse success
foo()
bar(a,b,42,)
qux(someThing_awful01=9,)
Remaining unparsed input: '
'
```